# Cannot connect: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

I ran following sql, but still receive access denied error:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Code used to connect is:

```
<?php

  $dbhost = 'localhost';
  $dbuser = 'username';
  $pass = '12345';
  $dbname = 'dbname';

  $dsn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $pass, $dbname);
```

Comment: Did you run it with dbname being currently selected database? I mean ```use dbname;``` prior grant

Comment: Yes, I ran the grant command after 'use dbname;'

Comment: I can access the database using the same credentials from the windows command line and from the phpmyadmin login screen; but, php script returns error.

Comment: I solved my problem by adding port 3308:  i.e.  '$dbhost='localhost:3308';;